# GridView 3d animation

Tags: android, animation, gridview, 3d, launcher

I need to create a grid view exactly like this:

[image]

This feature is being used by many launchers (ADW launcher Ex, Go Ex)

I have been able to create a normal GridView using BaseAdapter. However I have no idea about creating this animation. Please help me with ideas regarding how to proceed in order to achieve something like this.